# How to make google mock set a pointer (initially null) when calling the mock?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

My mock

```
namespace iobox::services
{
    class web_api_mock : public iweb_api
    {
    public:

        MOCK_METHOD(
                (bool), 
                http_get, 
                (const etl_normal_string &, char*, size_t&), 
                (override));
        MOCK_METHOD(
                (bool), 
                http_post, 
                (const etl_normal_string &, const char*), 
                (override));
    };
}
```

A snippet from my unit test:

```
etl_normal_string category("mdb");
const size_t size = 100;
char json_response[size] = "{\n"
    "\t\"mdb\": \n"
    "\t\t{ \"always_idle\": true, \"multi_vend\": false, \"default_available_funds\": 123 }\n"
    "}\n";

EXPECT_CALL(
    _web_api_mock, 
    http_get(category, _, _))
    .WillOnce(
        DoAll(
            SetArgPointee<1>(*json_response),
            Return(true)));
```

The actual implementation

```
char * contents = nullptr; // NOTE initially the pointer is set null
size_t size;

if (_web_api.http_get( // Calling this mock gives a segmentation fault
    category.c_str(),
    contents,
    size))
{
  // ...
}
```

The call to the mock gives a segmentation fault.

[image]

How do I setup the mock so that it does give the expected behavior? I want the `contents` pointer to point to my json string defined in my test code. I can't seem to get it right.

`SetArgPointee<1>(*json_response)` also feels wrong. I don't want to set the pointer to the first char of that string. I don't want to dereference the pointer `json_response` but I need to in order to get it compiled.

Comment: It's not possible to do that with `http_get` declared as such, with or without GMock. You can remove all the GTest context for a minimal example: https://godbolt.org/z/EorTxr4GE. You pass `char*` argument by value, so any modification of that argument within the body of `http_get` will not be reflected on the outside.

Comment: argh....! facepalm moment. Thank you!!